# extracting/sharing information

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Im building an app that helps prevent patients from going missing or helps locate them ... im able to get co_ordinates and send them to the defined number via sms. because of time constraints im looking for help narrowing down what i should look into before attacking the next section. The question is there there a better way to go about sharing data between two apps on different devices rather than sms.

any tips on extracting information from messages would also be great ty.

Comment: build your own push notification server.. or just send emails

Answer (score 0):

I think push notifications may be the way forward for you, check out this write up from Google about how to implement them:

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: note that the solution you came up with first (SMS), is probably overall more relieable because it won't require the devices to be on the internet. Whereas push notification will.

Comment: thanks for the comments lads av to have demo done for 4th project in a few weeks anything i cant implement i can recommend in the report. be more than likely asking plenty of questions all things android in the coming weeks ... if ye have any opinions on them all help is appreciated ty again